# WordPress Responsive Theme Not Being Fully Responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, user-interface, responsive-design, themes

I am using the Pictorico theme on my site (http://linktick.com/). When you resize the window, for whatever reason, there is an additional block of blue to the right of the content that you can horizontally scroll to:

[image]

However, when you look at a WordPress demo of the theme (http://pictoricodemo.wordpress.com/) and you resize it, this additional blue block does not appear - no horizontal scrolling option is available at all:

[image]

How can I make my site behave like this as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 885px) {
   .screen-reader-text { display: none; } 
}
```